# Dynamically change row index in loc method of pandas

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, iteration, pandas-loc

I have a DatetimeIndex with the name **idx**:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2020-10-24 21:00:00+03:00', '2020-10-24 23:00:00+03:00',
           '2020-10-25 08:00:00+03:00', '2020-10-26 08:00:00+03:00',
           '2020-10-27 13:00:00+03:00', '2020-10-29 07:00:00+03:00',
           '2020-10-29 22:00:00+03:00', '2020-10-31 01:00:00+03:00',
           '2020-11-01 16:00:00+03:00', '2020-11-03 18:00:00+03:00',
           '2020-11-04 20:00:00+03:00', '2020-11-05 17:00:00+03:00'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns, Europe/Moscow]', freq=None)
```

I need to iterate through dataframe rows to calculate cumulative max of 'close' column from each
**idx** element to the next, then from the following to the next, and so on.
It works well by doing:

```
for i in np.arange(len(idx)):
    signals.loc[idx[i]:, 'close_max'] = signals.loc[idx[i]:, 'close'].cummax(axis=0)
```

But iterating a dataframe is not a good thing. Could you help to make this without for loop?

[image]

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to do but do you think that it's possible to do it in parallel or you need to produce extra data for every row?

Comment: @Charalamm I need to find max value of 'close' column for each interval between the time stamps from idx

Comment: Still don't fully get it, sorry for that. Did you try `.apply()`? It applies the function inside the parenthesis in the whole column

Answer (score 1):

You can find the integer indices where your `idx` values are within `df.index` by using [np.searchsorted](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) (bonus: it works even if values of `idx` are not found in `df.index`).

Once you have these integer indices, build a `grp` value suitable for grouping your df. Then `groupby` and apply `cummax`.

Putting it all together:

```
ix = np.concatenate(([0], np.searchsorted(df.index, idx), [df.shape[0]]))
grp = np.repeat(ix[:-1], np.diff(ix))
df['close_max'] = df['close'].groupby(grp).cummax()
```

**Validation:**

First, let's build some data similar to yours, for testing:

```
n = 1000
df = pd.DataFrame(
    420 + np.round(np.cumsum(np.random.normal(size=n)), 2),
    columns=['close'],
    index=pd.date_range('2020-10-24', periods=n, freq='h'))

idx = [
    pd.Timestamp('2020-10-24') + k * pd.Timedelta('1 hour')
    for k in np.cumsum(np.random.randint(1, 48, size=n))
]
idx =[t for t in idx if df.first_valid_index() <= t <= df.last_valid_index()]
idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(idx)
```

Then, your "signals" calculation, slightly modified so as to not have NaNs:

```
signals = df[['close']].copy()
signals['close_max'] = signals['close'].cummax()
for t in idx:
    signals.loc[t:, 'close_max'] = signals.loc[t:, 'close'].cummax()

# apply the three lines in the solution above to add 'close_max' to df
# and finally:

signals.equals(df)
# True
```

Comment: Thank you! It works just fine and four times faster than in a for-loop.